# how to get off result for the rest checkboxes

Tags: node.js

I used req.body to get answer of checkboxes using post method
The result was like this

```
{
1:"on", 
2:"on",
4:"on"
}
```

But rest of them not even appeared or gave result as off

Comment: Can you post the code where you execute your POST request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.